# git shortlog in a GitHub-Workflow for a specific directory

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I want to print the shortlog for a specific directory (part of my repository) in my GitHub-Workflow.

I use the git command `git shortlog -e -n -s -- myFolder`

I use the `checkout@v3` action to check out my repo/pull-request as following:

```yaml
uses: actions/checkout@v3
with:
    ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
    fetch-depth: 0
```

My job runs on ubuntu-latest.

The problem is, the shortlog is always empty.

`git log` works fine (GitHub-Action)

Local it works fine (macOS).

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git shortlog` has a "feature" (misfeature, in my opinion, but [it is documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog) so it's not technically a *bug* ):

> If no revisions are passed on the command line and either standard
> input is not a terminal or there is no current branch, `git shortlog`
> will output a summary of the log read from standard input, without
> reference to the current repository.

When run as part of a GitHub action, standard input is not a terminal, which suffices to invoke this mode.  (It's also true that, at least sometimes, there is no current branch, which would also trigger this behavior.)

As such, *you must run `git log` yourself* and feed the `git log` output *to* `git shortlog` as its standard input (e.g., `git log | git shortlog`) so that `git shortlog` can summarize it.

Side note:

> ```
> fetch-depth: 0
> ```

Good work: you successfully avoided the *other* trap with GitHub actions.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks a lot. Not sure I like the behavior of `shortlog`, but if it is in the documentation, the fault is mine.